# Is it possible to write a bash script that can use another program with a graphical interface to do edits to a file?

Tags: bash

I am modifying a protein by swapping certain amino acids using a program that I have downloaded on my computer. Let's call it ProteinApp. Is it possible to use a bash script to open a file in ProteinApp, then click the appropriate buttons within the application to edit and save the file? I am only familiar with using bash scripts to edit text files in the terminal, but I wonder if I could edit them using a program that edits the files in a more sophisticated manner. This way, I could write a bash script to loop through a bunch of protein files instead of having to manually edit them myself with the program. I know it is easy to open the file I want in ProteinApp, which is my default application.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
open FILE.pdb
```

But then after this, is it possible to use bash to select a certain part of the screen or something like that? If not bash, is there any general way to program your computer to click on certain parts of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the App on Windows, there are several tools with GUI to use for faking mouse input, if you are on Linux and want it to be clean and controlable, you can use PyAutoGUI. After importing pyautogui, you can get the coordinates of the buttons you want to click on by using:

```
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
```

Then you can imitate the click using:

```
pyautogui.click(100, 200) #Put in the actual coordinates of the buttons
```

Comment: do you know how to do this on a mac?

Comment: It's the same as on Mac, you can install the library using pip, then writing the scrips to control the mouse to do the tasks you'd like to